# Simple React Test Failing Even Though Correct Props Being Passed In

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to run what I assume should be a fairly simple test on a modal component within my React project, but for whatever reason the test keeps failing. And that's the case even though I can see that I am passing in the correct props that should make the component render as expected.

My modal code looks lke this:

import React from 'react';
import { Dialog, DialogFooter, DefaultButton, PrimaryButton, DialogType } from '@fluentui/react';

```
const Modal = (props) => {
  console.log('Modal is firing...', props); // I see the correct props here, passed in via the test
  if (!props.showModal) return null;

  if (props.showModal) {
    return (
      <Dialog
        hidden={!props.showModal}
        data-testid="modal"
        dialogContentProps={{
          type: DialogType.normal,
          title: props.title,
          subText: props.subText,
        }}
        modalProps={{
          isBlocking: false,
        }}
      >
        <DialogFooter>
          <PrimaryButton
            text="Yes"
            onClick={() => {
              props.confirm();
              props.close();
            }}
          />
          <DefaultButton
            text="No"
            onClick={() => {
              props.close();
            }}
          />
        </DialogFooter>
      </Dialog>
    );
  };
}

export default Modal;
```

And here is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import Modal from './Modal';

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation(() => {});
});

it('renders modal correctly', () => {
  const props = { title: "A Test Title", subText: "Test subtext", showModal: true };
  const { getByText } = render(<Modal props={props} />);
  expect(getByText('Test subtext')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

And the error I'm getting upon test failure is this:

> Unable to find an element with the text: Test subtext. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case,
> you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher
> more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test, try spreading the props, like:

```
render(<Modal {...props} />)
```